# How can I make Dolphin open bookmarks in the current tab?

Tags: dolphin-browser

I have loaded the Dolphin browser on my HTC Android phone.

Each time I open my bookmark it loads a new tab in the browser which means I have many running and I have to go in and close the tabs.

Does anyone know how to make it use an existing tab of the browser? I don't want the browser to have so many tabs open. I realise this will mean if I have TWO apps the previous will show then open the bookmark. Alternatively, is it possible to have Dolphin close my tabs when the `Home` button is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Dolphin:
Menu Button > Settings (ship's wheel) > Customize > Open links in > By default

**Default** will open in the page is set up to open the link into (normally the same page), other choices are **Open in background tab** (current tab remains the active tab), and **Open in new tab**.

Older versions of Dolphin had option under Labs instead of under Customize.

---

Optional:

I find it best to stick with the default open in the same tab, but will often use a bookmarklet to force tabs to open in a new tab when I want to make sure I don't fail to use the context menu to open a link in a new tab, for which I assign a gesture written as "nt" in Dolphin, or a keyword shortcut of "nt:" in Firefox (where : is not hard to type on a keyboard).

**Name**:     NT:  New Tab
**Address**:  javascript:(function(){var%20a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');document.title='||'+document.title+'||';for(var%20i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){a[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');}})();

When creating the bookmarklet in Dolphin, create by replacing content of a newly created bookmarklet with the above content, typing a space instead of  %20 and  and suggest changing the folder to one you have created as "bookmarklets" within your bookmarks.

see my page on [Dolphin Gestures](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/dolphin/dolphin_gestures.htm)